# Can't upload multiple image using Ajax with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Wana to upload multiple image with the help of Ajax in codeigniter but  got some error while calling the function upload_business_photo_do() please help

thanks in advance....

```
<input type="button" id="uploadBusinessImg" value="Upload">
```

Ajax Code:- here i call ajax via `id="uploadBusinessImg"`

```
<script>

    $("#uploadBusinessImg").on("click",function(e)
    {
         var total_img=$("#txtBusinessImage").get(0).files.length;
         if(total_img<=5)
         {
             var f_size=0;
             var f_size_1=0;
             var f_type_1="" ,validFileName="",InValidFileName="";
             var chkFileValid=true;
             for(var i=0; i<=total_img-1; i++)
             {
                 var f_name=$("#txtBusinessImage").get(0).files.item(i).name;
                 var f_size=$("#txtBusinessImage").get(0).files.item(i).size;
                 var f_type=f_name.split('.').pop();
                 //alert(f_type);
                 var valid_extensions = /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png)$/i;
                 if(valid_extensions.test(f_name))
                    { 
                        if(validFileName=="")
                            validFileName =f_name;
                        else
                            validFileName+=","+f_name;
                    }
                 else
                    {   InValidFileName=f_name;
                        chkFileValid=false;
                        break;
                    }   

                var newFileSize=parseInt(f_size);
                f_size_1=parseInt(f_size_1)+parseInt(newFileSize);

             }
             var totalFileSize=f_size_1;
             //alert(totalFileSize);
             if(totalFileSize<=1572864 && chkFileValid==true)
             {
                 //alert("allow");
                 alert(validFileName);
                 var businessIMAGE=validFileName;
                 $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"<?php echo site_url('Main_ctrl/upload_business_photo_do'); ?>",
                        mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
                        uploadMultiple: true,
                        data:{reciveBusinessImg:businessIMAGE},
                        success: function(reviceUploadImgMsg)
                        {
                            alert(reviceUploadImgMsg);
                        }
                 });

             }
             else
             {   
                if(chkFileValid==false)
                    alert("InValidFileName"+InValidFileName);
                else
                    alert("Image size should be less then 1.5 MB");
             }
         }
         else
         {
            alert("Not Allow");
         }


    });

    </script>
```

This is Controller Code:-

```
function upload_business_photo_do()
    {
        $reciveBusinessImgName=$this->input->post('reciveBusinessImg');
        $newArray=explode(",",$reciveBusinessImgName);
        /*code for image*/
                $config['upload_path']='./company_image/';
                $config['allowed_types']= 'jpg|png|jpeg';
                $config['max_width'] = '6000';
                $config['max_height'] = '4500';

                $this->load->library('upload',$config);


                for($i=0; $i<count($newArray); $i++)
                {
                    $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $_FILES['txtBusinessImage']['name'][$i];

                    $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $_FILES['txtBusinessImage']['type'][$i];
                    $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $_FILES['txtBusinessImage']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $_FILES['txtBusinessImage']['error'][$i];
                    $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $_FILES['txtBusinessImage']['size'][$i];


                        if(! $this->upload->do_upload())
                        {
                            /*----set flash message*/
                            echo "error";


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
                             echo "done";
                        }

                }
    }
```

Comment: show header of post request and var_dump array $_FILES

Comment: i don't see any FormData in your code